# res.redirect keeps getting called multiple times but doesnt redirect

Tags: node.js, express-session, response.redirect

My express app:

```
const https = require("https");
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require("cors");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const logger = require("morgan");
const compression = require("compression");
const session = require("express-session");
const pgSession = require("connect-pg-simple")(session);
const api = require("../server/routes");
const pool = require("../config/database");
/** ====== DotENV configuration */
dotenv.config({ path: require("find-config")(".env") });

const configurations = {
    production: { ssl: true, port: process.env.PORT, hostname: "" },
    development: {
        ssl: false,
        port: process.env.PORT,
        hostname: process.env.STAGE_HOSTNAME,
    },
};

const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = configurations[environment];

const {
    responseHandlerMiddleware,
    sessionChecker,
} = require("../server/middlewares");

const app = express();

var credentials = {
    // key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/myresorts.in/privkey.pem"),
    // cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/myresorts.in/fullchain.pem"),
};

let server = config.ssl
    ? https.createServer(credentials, app)
    : http.createServer(app);

app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "20mb" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(
    session({
        store: new pgSession({
            pool,
            tableName: "session",
        }),
        name: "user_sid",
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
        resave: false,
        cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 600000000000 },
        saveUninitialized: false,
    })
);
app.set("views", path.resolve(__dirname, "../views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("../public"));

app.get("/", sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/login");
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});

app.route("/login").get(sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
    res.render("pages/login");
});
app.route("/register").get(sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
    res.render("pages/register");
});
app.route("/dashboard").get(sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
        res.render("pages/dashboard");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
});

app.use("/", sessionChecker, api);

module.exports = server;
```

`sessionChecker` middleware:

```
const sessionChecker = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("sesson ---------", req.session.user);
    console.log("cookies ---------", JSON.stringify(req.cookies));
    if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
    } else {
        return next();
    }
};
```

`registerUser`:

```
const catchAsync = require("../utilities/catchAsync");
const {
    generatePassword,
    validatePassword,
} = require("../utilities/passwordUtilities");
const pool = require("../../config/database");

const registerUser = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await pool.query("select * from find_user_by_email($1)", [
        email,
    ]);
    if (user.rowCount) {
        res.error = "User already exists";
        return next(500);
    }
    const saltHash = generatePassword(password);
    const response = await pool.query("select * from create_user($1, $2, $3)", [
        email,
        saltHash.salt,
        saltHash.hash,
    ]);
    if (response.rowCount) {
        req.session.user = { email: response.rows[0].create_user };
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/register");
    }
});
```

The redirect to `/dashboard` should take me to the dashboard after registering. But, that doesn't seem to happen, instead, this keeps getting called multiple times and then it stops:

```
GET /dashboard 302 255.451 ms - 64
```

Also, the `console.log` print nothing in the session checker. That is another issue in the same app above.

Comment: How do you make a request and what is its URL?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Its hosted in local.

Comment: Do you use `fetch` to make a request?

Comment: No, plain html template.

Comment: So you are sending a form to `/register` and you want to be redirected to `/dashboard` after that?

Comment: Yes, preserving the session.

Comment: And the url doesn't change?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I'm rendering the pages from the server only. The url is localhost.

Comment: You clearly have route `/register` required, why don't you use ut?